# The REST API gives correct response in Postman, but gives Volley ServerError

Tags: android, rest, android-volley, server-error

I'm sending an array of images to the REST API which returns the form fields after digitization. My app has minimum API level 21. I'm using `Android Volley` to send and receive data to/from the REST API.

The code works perfectly for a single image, but then it fails when more than one image is sent. A few answers here suggested *clearing the cache in the queue*, but it's already present in the code and that's not solving the problem.

Also, there is no problem in the back-end code, because it works fine in Postman, but the response fails in Android. Right now, I'm trying it on Marshmallow. It works rarely. The API doesn't seem to be the problem.

---

JSON request:

```
{

    "imageFormat": "jpeg",

    "formType": "dummyForm",

    "images": 
    [
          "//base64 of image1", 
          "//base64 of image2", //as many as required       
    ]
}
```

JSON response:

```
{
   "dummyLines": // Response from all images' form fields is in this array
    [
        {
            "confidence": "high",
            "key": "FIRST NAME :",
            "value": "ABC"
        },
        ...
        // The above set is repeated for all form fields
    ],
    "dummyStatus": "Succeeded",
    "message": "none"
}
```

### EDIT:

These are the classes which handle request and response:

`DummyRequest` class

```
public class DummyRequest
{
    String imageFormat;
    String formType;
    String images[];
}
```

`DummyImageResponse` class

```
public class DummyImageResponse implements Serializable
{
    ArrayList<FieldsJson> dummyLines = new ArrayList<>();
    String dummyStatus;
}
```

`FieldsJson` class

```
public class FieldsJson implements Serializable
{
    String key;
    String value;
    String confidence;
}
```

### EDIT

This code encodes the `Bitmap` images to `Base64`:

```
for(int i=0; i<cameraImageAdapter.getCount(); i++)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedImagePathList.get(i));
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] imageByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    cameraEncodedImages[i] = Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

### EDIT

I've included some additional code in the onErrorResponse method and I got the below stack trace. 
This is the code which calls the API:

```
ResponseHandler responseHandler = new ResponseHandler(
                API_URL,
                DummyImageResponse.class,
                request,
                new HashMap<String, String>(),
                new Response.Listener<DummyImageResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(DummyImageResponse response) {
                        Log.e("Success response", response.toString());

                        // Call new activity to display the result
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Error response", error.toString());
                        NetworkResponse errorResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if(error instanceof ServerError && errorResponse != null)
                        {
                            try {
                                Log.e("In error response", "Response not null");
                                String response = new String(errorResponse.data,
                                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(errorResponse.headers, "UTF-8"));
                                Log.e("Parsed response", response);
                            }
                            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                            {
                                Log.e("In error response", e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            Log.e("In error response", "Response is null");

                        // Call new activity to display error message
                    }
                }
        );

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        responseHandler.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                50000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        queue.getCache().clear();       // Clear the queue
        queue.add(responseHandler);     // Request is sent to the REST API
```

---

The expected output must contain all the fields in the form. However, when multiple images are involved, the JSON response is most likely getting corrupted for some reason and that might be generating the `ServerError` due to some `glassfish` library which parses JSON, I read so. I'm not sure.

Possibly, this could be because Android and Postman handle JSON data a little differently.

---

This is the exact error message which I get:

```
E/Volley: [18942] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for **URL goes here**
E/Error response: com.android.volley.ServerError
E/In error response: Response not null
E/Parsed response: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:408)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    </pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
        java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
        com.example.ICRAPI.GetGender.main(GetGender.java:21)
        com.example.ICRAPI.dummyForm.main(dummyForm.java:178)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletConta
```

Comment: post your request model and response model

Comment: @Boopathi, I've added the Java classes to handle the JSON data. Please check now.

Comment: request looks good. Post response here before serializing response object. I mean corrupted response.

Comment: @Boopathi, it's not generating any response. The error response listener is called which just prints the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ok that's fine, Post image conversion code to base 64.

Comment: @Boopathi, I've added the code which encodes the images to Base64. Please check.

Comment: Your code looks good to me but issue is strange. There could be lot of reason for errors. Please explore about multipart request in volley that might help you to out in this issue.

Comment: @Boopathi, I added some code in the Error response listener and I got the above stack trace. Can you please check it?